# Simplifying the `import as` syntax

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I'm currently importing a few lodash functions with the following syntax:

`import {cloneDeep as _cloneDeep, each as _each, size as _size} from 'lodash'`

This works, but it's kind of annoying to have to specify each `as` variable renaming. Are there any shortcuts that would avoid this? I'd be happy to have all those methods inside an object as well, to simulate the functionality of when the entire lodash library is imported, e.g. `_.cloneDeep`, `_.each`, etc.

To clarify, I don't want to import the entire library. So I'm looking for a solution that still allows the modular importing of functions.

Comment: Why are you renaming the import to begin with? You can do `import {cloneDeep} from 'lodash';`

Comment: @loganfsmyth namespacing to avoid conflicts, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to avoid annoyance I suspect this may not be what you want but if you're very set on the consumer syntax and want individual importing for efficient packing or something you could always create an intermediary module.

This module will import the contents that you want and in your main code you can reference the intermediary module in the way you're hoping to.

As an example:

```
import {parse as _parse, join as _join} from 'path'

export var parse = _parse;
export var join = _join;
```

and in your main application,

```
import * as path from './custom-lib/path'

path.parse(...);
```

It involves an extra file which sucks, but you do only have to write it once.

I wouldn't necessarily call this a good solution, but I think this is the closest you're going to get to what you want with the current standards.

Comment: This seems like a good solution! I'll use it to export an object, so that I can just `import _ from ...`, thus causing the function calls to appear like standard lodash ones

Answer (score 0):

ECMA2015 has the option to import all into one object/container.

`import * as _ from 'lodash'`

then you can use it as before:

`_.cloneDeep()`, `_.each()`, etc...

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. Should have clarified that I'm looking for a solution that still allows for modular function importing. I have updated my post to make this more obvious.

Comment: Oh ok, haven't seen something like that (or if that's possible). The whole point of modular importing is so that you don't need to use single object/container paradigm. And allows for replacing the imported library with another library easily (e.g. going back to underscore), although I can understand why you'd want to rename some of them. Here's a reference to possible ways to use import: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Answer (score 0):

You can import the whole lib as well as individual methods:

```
import _, { cloneDeep, each, isArray } from 'lodash';

_.isArray([]) // true
isArray([])   // true
```

When you do `import x from 'y';` it will store the whole `y` module in the `x` variable.

Doing `import {a, b, c} from 'y';` will just pull in the specific methods `a, b, c` of the module.

You can combine both types of import by just delimiting them with a comma as I did in the example.

Learn more at [MDN's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).